# Numpy: manipulate elements depending on the value without looping over the entire array

Tags: numpy, if-statement, boolean

I have a numpy array x and I would like to perform an action on the elements of x depending on its value. For example suppose I want to take the square for all negative elements and take the fourth power for all the other elements. The following code does the trick

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([-2,-1,0,1,2,3])
y = np.zeros(len(x))

for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i]<0:
        y[i] = np.square(x[i])
    else:
        y[i] = np.power(x[i],4)

print(y)
```

Since I am handling large arrays and performing this action many times, I am looking for a way to do this without looping over all elements.

Comment: You have to learn `numpy` and its methods and ufuncs.  As the answer shows, there are tools for applying various math operations to the whole array - square, power, multiplication, etc.  There isn't one magically function that will take a iteative calculation, and turn it into a compiled one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generically

```
mask = x<0
y[mask] = fn1(x[mask])
mask =~mask
y[mask] = fn2(x[mask])
```

The mask test and the fn are written to work with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([-2,-1,0,1,2,3])
mask1 = np.clip(x,0,None)
mask1 = np.power(mask1,4)
mask2 = np.clip(x,None,0)
mask2 = np.power(mask2,2)
res = mask1+mask2
```

output

```
array([ 4,  1,  0,  1, 16, 81], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! This works for this very specific example, but what if I need more complicated conditions and operations, such as taking cos(x)*exp(-x^2) for x^2-7x+8>0 and take x^3+8 otherwise?

Comment: could you explain it in question.I answered for what you asked in question